# No qualifying bean of type 'repository.PersonRepository' available

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I m trying to follow a Spring Boot example  , I searched on internet for few hours without find a solution to my case . most of solution I found they said to put @ComponentScan to scan the package , am I missing something , any hep is appreciated .

SpringBootApplication class:

```
package ben;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"services","repository", "web"}) 
public class SpringBootWebApplication
{
public static void main (String  [] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
  }

}
```

PersonRepository class:

```
package ben.repository;

@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Bde, Integer> {

}
```

PersonService:

```
package ben.services;

import models.Bde;

public interface PersonService
{
  public Iterable <Bde> findAll();
}
```

PersonServiceImpl:

```
package ben.services;

@Service

public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService
{
  @Autowired
  private PersonRepository personRepository;

  @Override
  public Iterable<Bde> findAll()
  {

    return personRepository.findAll();
  }

}
```

PersonRest class:

```
package ben.web;    
@RestController
public class PersonRest
{
  @Autowired
  //@Qualifier("PersonServiceImpl")
  private PersonService personService;

  @RequestMapping("/person")
  @ResponseBody
  public  Iterable <Bde> findAll() {

    Iterable <Bde> persons=personService.findAll();
    return persons;
  }

}
```

package structure updated like suggested :

[image]

Comment: updated as suggested by  @sfat and  Wim Deblauwe. still have the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limiting yourself to the package `service`

```
@ComponentScan("services")
```

this is equal to

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "services")
```

You need to specify all packages in order for your beans to be instantiated

An example on how to scan all your beans (services, repository and web)

```
@ComponentScan({"services","repository", "web"})
```

As an alternative you can do the following:

1. move everything in a package and the `SpringBootWebApplication` class would sit at the root of that package.

An example:

[image: Everything in a package]

All your app sits on `com.yourapp`.
If you put the `SpringBootWebApplication` in `com.yourapp`, there is not need for the `@ComponentScan` annotation anymore and your class gets simplified just with the `@SpringBootApplication`:

```
package com.yourapp;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are only scanning your services package.

Try this...

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "services", "repository" })
```

Comment: Or just put everything in subpackages of the package that your main application class is in.

Answer (score 1):

Change your directory structure to the following:

```
ben---- SpringBootWebApplication.java (pkg: ben)
|
----repository (pkg: ben.repository)
|      |
|       ------ PersonRepository
|
----services (pkg: ben.services)
|
----web (pkg: ben.web)
```

and then update your SpringBootWebApplication class

```
package ben

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootWebApplication
{
    public static void main (String  [] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootWebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```